# node not getting deleted if it's the head

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list, function-definition

This is my code, the important part at least.  Whenever I run it and try to delete the `head` node, it won't work (the output will be a large negative number). It will work for all other nodes.

Is it something with my code, or you just can't replace the `head`?

```
node* displayList(node* head) {
    node* curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << " ";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

node* deleteVal(node* head, int val) {
    node* cur, * prev;
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;
    
    if (head->data == val) {
        cur = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = cur;
        return head;
    }
    cur = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while (cur->data != val && cur != NULL) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (cur == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    prev->next = cur->next;
    return head;
}

int main() {
    node* head1 = initNode(), * head2=initNode(), * head3 = initNode();
    int val;
    head1 = input();
    head2 = input();
    head3 = input();
    conca(head1, head2, head3);
    cout << "the concatated list is: ";
    displayList(head1);
    cout << endl<<"enter the value you want to delete: ";
    cin >> val;
    deleteVal(head1, val);
    cout << "the new list is: ";
    displayList(head1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you deleted head and re assigned it to some other value, that is fishy

Comment: You returned the new head from your `node* deleteVal(node* head, int val) {` but threw it away in `int main()` with the call: `deleteVal(head1, val);` by ignoring the return value from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deleteVal()` is coded wrong.

When NOT removing the `head` node, your `while` loop will exhibit **undefined behavior** if `val` is not found in the list.  In that situation, `cur` will become `NULL` after the last node is checked, and then the loop will try to access `cur->data` one more time, which is UB.

You need to swap the conditions of the `while` statement so that `cur` is checked for `NULL` *before* its `data` member is accessed:

```
while (cur != NULL && cur->data != val)
```

Also, if the `while` loop does find `val` in the remaining nodes, you are simply unlinking the found node from the list, but you are not actually `delete`'ing that node, thus you are leaking its memory.

Try this instead:

```
node* deleteVal(node* head, int val) {
    node *cur, *prev;
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;
    
    if (head->data == val) {
        cur = head->next;
        delete head;
        return cur;
    }

    // we know the head node doesn't match, no need to
    // test it again, so start the loop on the 2nd node...
    cur = head->next;
    prev = head;

    while (cur != NULL && cur->data != val) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (cur != NULL) {
        prev->next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Now, that being said, there are other issues with the code shown.

`main()` is ignoring the return value of `deleteVal()`.  So, if the node pointed to by `head1` were actually removed/deleted from the list, `main()` has no way of knowing that, and thus ends up passing a now-invalid `node*` pointer to `displayList()` afterwards. So, you need to assign the return value of `deleteVal()` back to `head1` to reflect the new list state:

```
head1 = deleteVal(head1, val);
```

This is why it is not a good design choice to return a new list pointer by return value (unless you mark it as [`nodiscard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) in C++17 and later), as it is too easy to ignore.  A better design choice is to pass in the caller's variable by reference/pointer instead, so the function can update the caller's variable directly when needed.

Also, `main()` is leaking the `head1`, `head2`, and `head3` nodes when calling `input()`.  You are creating new nodes with `initNode()`, and then reassigning the pointers to point at new nodes created by `input()`, thus you lose access to the original nodes from `initNode()`.

In fact, even after calling `deleteVal()`, you are not freeing any remaining nodes before exiting the program.  While it is true that the OS will reclaim all used memory when the program exits, it is best practice to explicitly free anything you allocate.

Also, your `deleteVal()` is needlessly complex, it can be greatly simplified.

Also, there is no good reason for `displayList()` to return anything at all.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
void displayList(node* head) {
    node* curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << " ";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void deleteVal(node* &head, int val) {
    node *cur = head, **prev = &head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->data == val) {
            *prev = cur->next;
            delete cur;
            return;
        }
        prev = &(cur->next);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(node* &head) {
    node *cur = head, *next;
    head = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = next;
    }
}

int input() { // <-- return int, not node* !
    ...
    return ...; // <-- just the user's entered value, not a node wrapping the value
}

int main() {
    node* head1 = initNode(), *head2 = initNode(), *head3 = initNode();
    head1->data = input();
    head2->data = input();
    head3->data = input();
    conca(head1, head2, head3);
    cout << "the concatenated list is: ";
    displayList(head1);
    cout << "enter the value you want to delete: ";
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    deleteVal(head1, val);
    cout << "the new list is: ";
    displayList(head1);
    deleteList(head1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: worked unless for return int not node* in input(), (i tried returning head->data) so i kept it as a node and head1=input()...

Comment: You are missing my point.  There is no good reason for `input()` to return *a node* at all, it should return just *the user's entered input value* instead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the condition of the while loop

```
while (cur->data != val && cur != NULL) {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

must be changed like

```
while ( cur != nullptr && cur->data != val) {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

Also you need indeed to delete the found node like

```
prev->next = cur->next;
delete cur;
return head;
```

And in main you have to reassign the pointer to the head node like

```
head1 = deleteVal(head1, val);
```

With shown updates the function can look the following way

```
node* deleteVal(node* head, int val) {
    node* cur, * prev;
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;
    
    if (head->data == val) {
        cur = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = cur;
        return head;
    }
    cur = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while ( cur != NULL && cur->data != val ) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (cur == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    prev->next = cur->next;
    delete cur;
    return head;
}
```

And in main write

```
head1 = deleteVal(head1, val);
```

Comment: but why is that? first of all the while loop works as i wrote it since it doesn't affect the head, (plus i got it from the college course but never mind it). secondly, should the code below be placed in the while loop or in if(head->data==val)? because i wrote it in the "if" and didn't work.   ```prev->next = cur->next;
delete cur;
return head;```

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn "*the while loop works as i wrote it*" - no, it doesn't. `cur->data != val` is evaluated BEFORE `cur != NULL`, so if `cur` **IS** `NULL` (ie, because the loop reaches the end of the list without finding `val`), then accessing `cur->data` is **undefined behavior**. So you have to make sure that `cur` **IS NOT** `NULL` first.

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn After an iteration of the while loop the pointer cur can be a null pointer. So using a null pointer in the expression cur->data invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but does using NULL instead of nullptr wrong?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but deleting the head is still not working and that's my problem.

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn Are you reassigning the header as I showed?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes, here's the changes: `if (head->data == val) {
  prev->next = cur->next;
  delete cur;
  return head;
 }
 cur = head;
 prev = NULL;
 while (cur!=NULL && cur->data != val) {
  prev = cur;
  cur = cur->next;
 }` and `head1 = deleteVal(head1, val);` and i had to initiate prev and cur like that but could be wrong initialization. and sorry for the messed up comment

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn I do not understand where this code appeared from. All changes that you need to do is described in my answer. Can you do the updates I showed? What is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i updated my post with the changes if you could check it

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn your change introduces new **undefined behavior**, because `prev` and `cur` are not valid pointers yet if `head->data` is a match for `val`. Your original code to delete the `head` node was fine, it was the logic handling nodes AFTER the `head` node that wasn't fine.

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn Please return the previous content of the question because the new changes will only confuse readers of the question and answer and I totally do not understand what you are doing. One more make changes I showed in my answer. What is the problem?

Comment: @AnthonyGhosn I have rolled back your changes to the question. if you want to show your updated code, put it as an edit UNDERNEATH the original code, so you don't invalidate previous comments/answers that were referring to the original code.